# How many bytes are needed to reserve space in memory to variables

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, exploit

I'm a beginner in the study of exploits and I am starting from the beginning, how memory works. I'm following the Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit text. In the first example they disassembly a code and explains what is happening. What I can't understand is why did my machine reserve 30 Bytes when 20 is enough - like in the example.

Here is my C code:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c){
    char buffer1[5];
    char buffer2[10];
}

void main (){
    function(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Here is the disassembly of function:

```
(gdb) disass function 
Dump of assembler code for function function:
   0x000000000000066a <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000000066b <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000066e <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x0000000000000672 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x24(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000675 <+11>:    mov    %esi,-0x28(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000678 <+14>:    mov    %edx,-0x2c(%rbp)
   0x000000000000067b <+17>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000000684 <+26>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000000688 <+30>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000000068a <+32>:    nop
   0x000000000000068b <+33>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000000068f <+37>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000000698 <+46>:    je     0x69f <function+53>
   0x000000000000069a <+48>:    callq  0x540 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x000000000000069f <+53>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000000006a0 <+54>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Try disabling the stack protector (`-fno-stack-protector`)

Comment: Now the subq operation disappears

Comment: Try disabling optimizations too (`-O0`), or actually using those variables so the compiler doesn't just eliminate them.

Comment: I did use the variables and disable optimizations. Still $48 Bytes.

Comment: What compiler are you using, what version, and what command line options?  And are you certain that what you've shown us is exactly the code you are compiling (you have two different versions in your question already)?  When I compile your code with gcc 9.3, the assembly doesn't look like what you showed.

Comment: I'm running the following command in gcc (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04):

Comment: gcc -S -O0 -o example1.s example1.c

Comment: The second version of the code is a modification of the first version, proposed by Mat

Comment: I updated my gcc, then I generated an executable file and finally I generated (by gdb)  the disassembly. The result is that there are 30 Bytes reserved, rather then 20.